# Using requestAnimationFrame in an Emberjs App

Tags: ember.js, requestanimationframe

I'm in the process of porting a ThreeJS rendered application into Ember, all has been fine with one exception.

The original js had the following functon:

```
function animate(){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}
```

The Ember method is very similar:

```
....
animate: function() {
  var view = this;
  requestAnimationFrame(view.animate);
  view.render();
},
....
```

The problem I have is that within the Emberjs view, the first run correctly maps to the render method when the second run happens, `var view = this` is bound to the window object, rather than the Ember view object, and so the animation method doesn't run.

Is there a way to map directly to the Ember Object method without relying on `this`

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing two different things here, a function assigned to property on a hash to a function scoped to its parent.

The function assigned to a property can only be run by using `instance.property`.

The function scoped to its parent is available anywhere within the scope of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
animate: function(context) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){context.animate(context)});
    context.render();
},
```

and at the first call of .animate() you should pass context parameter you are interested in